# Being both nonprivileged and root inside Docker container

Tags: docker, pandoc, fontconfig

I want to use pandoc inside docker. The image looks like this:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y pandoc texlive
WORKDIR /home
```

This is `build.sh` inside the project:

```
cp *.ttf /usr/local/share/fonts/ && fc-cache;
pandoc -o output.pdf input.md
```

that I want to run like this:

```
docker run --rm -t -v $(pwd):/home pandoc_container build.sh
```

This results in `output.pdf` being owned by root on my host. When doing:

```
docker run --user $(id -u) --rm -t -v $(pwd):/home pandoc_container build.sh
```

instead, the file will be owned by me, but the font files can not be copied to that dir, due to missing write permissions. Adding

```
RUN chmod a+w /usr/local/share/fonts/
```

to the Dockerfile solves this, but then the command `fc-cache` fails with a lot of `failed to write cache` errors also due to missing write permissions in lots of directories.

Copying the font files to `~/.fonts` will not work either, because the user created by `--user $(id -u)` does not actually exist in the container:

```
I have no name!@0d9c6a272ae1:/home$
```

and thus does not have a home directory, which could be parsed by `fc-cache`.

What's an elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as easy as adding

```
chown $UID output.pdf
```

to `build.sh` and then passing docker an env-var instead of the user id:

```
docker run -e UID=$(id -u) --rm -t -v $(pwd):/home pandoc_container build.sh
```